# How can i remove Userform Listbox item with todays date?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

Can anyone help? How can i remove item from listbox with todays date? i have tried the below but this does not remove item, the code works for example if i had "x" in the list (see code snippet 2)

```
For lngLoop = ListBox1.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
  If ListBox1.List(lngLoop, 2) = Now() Then
     ListBox1.RemoveItem (lngLoop)
  End If
Next

Code Snippet 2

For lngLoop = ListBox1.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
  If ListBox1.List(lngLoop, 2) = "x" Then
     ListBox1.RemoveItem (lngLoop)
  End If
Next
```

Full Code

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
TextBox1.Value = Sheets("Competency Overview").Range("G2")

Dim rng As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim t As Long

Set ws = Worksheets("Competency Review")
Set rng = ws.Range("C2:J2")
Set fnd = rng.Find(TextBox1)
If fnd Is Nothing Then MsgBox TextBox1 & " not found": Exit Sub
Set first = fnd
With ListBox1
    .Clear
    For t = 1 To 200
            .AddItem ws.Cells(4, 1).Range("A" & t + 0).Value
            .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = ws.Cells(4, 2).Range("A" & t + 
0).Value
            .List(.ListCount - 1, 2) = Format(fnd.Offset(t + 1, 
0).Value, "dd-mmm-yyyy")

        
        Next t
End With

Dim lngLoop As Long
    
For lngLoop = ListBox1.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
  If ListBox1.List(lngLoop, 2) = "x" Then
     ListBox1.RemoveItem (lngLoop)
  End If
Next

For lngLoop = ListBox1.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
Dim d As Date
d = DateValue(ListBox1.List(lngLoop, 2))
If d > Date - 14 Then
 ListBox1.RemoveItem (lngLoop)
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Kind Regards,
Andy

Comment: What is the format of the dates in the listbox dd.mm.yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy ? Now() includes time like `08/03/2023 10:51:29` , Date() would be `08/03/2023`

Comment: .List(.ListCount - 1, 2) = Format(fnd.Offset(t + 1, 0).Value, "dd-mmm-yy")

Comment: `Dim s as String : s = Format(Date,"dd-mmm-yy") `. Then use `If ListBox1.List(lngLoop, 2) = s Then`

Answer (score 0):

A listbox contains strings, not dates (or numbers...).
Using `format` converts a date into a string.

When you loop over the items and compare them to a date, you are forcing to convert the string back to a date so that they can be compared. That may or may not be working, depending on the format you wrote and the regional settings on your computer. An additional problem is that you are comparing against `Now()` which includes the time.

So instead of letting VBA convert the date string back into a date, do this vice versa: Convert the current date to a String (with the same format patterns) and compare that to the items:

```
For lngLoop = ListBox1.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
  If ListBox1.List(lngLoop, 2) = Format(Now(), "dd-mmm-yy") Then
     ListBox1.RemoveItem (lngLoop)
  End If
Next
```

**Update** If you want to remove entries from the last *nn* days, you will need to convert the item strings into dates. This might get tricky as you are using month abbreviations, but likely the following code should do:

```
For lngLoop = ListBox1.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
    Dim d as Date
    d = DateValue(ListBox1.List(lngLoop, 2))
    if d > Date - 14 Then
     ListBox1.RemoveItem (lngLoop)
  End If
Next
```

(`Date` returns the current date, but, different from `Now`, without the time).

Comment: Thank you working great, how would i change this to remove anything less than 14 days away?

    For lngLoop = ListBox1.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
  If ListBox1.List(lngLoop, 2) < Format(Now() + 14, "dd-mmm-yy") Then
     ListBox1.RemoveItem (lngLoop)
  End If
Next

Comment: Thank you for the swift reply - i get a runtime 13 error with this code

Comment: Is the date in your 3rd column `List(lngLoop, 2)` will access data from the 3rd column as the column index starts at 0? What is the content of `ListBox1.List(lngLoop, 2)` when the error occurs (check with the debugger)

Comment: Yes 3rd column is date or blank cell, the code fails at line
If d > Date - 14 Then

Comment: Do you have a variable or anything else with the name `Date`? Move the cursor to `Date` and press [Shift]+[F2]: What do you see? You could use `VBA.Date` in the `If`-statement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252380/discussion-between-andy-and-funthomas).

Comment: Hi, still getting Runtime error 13 i have added full code to original post
Kind Regards,
Andy

Comment: its now working dropped the date variable below Dim t As Long